# How can we get the column name of blank rows value of python dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-2.7

[image: Image with inputfile and the output example]

How can we get the column name of blank rows value of python dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can check them with `df.isna().any()`, if you want the columsn as a list you can use:

`dataframe.columns[dataframe.isna().any()].tolist()`